# MYSQL - Como retornar registros que existem em uma tabela e não existem em outra?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Tenho a tabela npsparticipantes que recebe o id que vem da tabela contratos. Como faço para recuperar todos os contratos que não estão adicionados a tabela npsparticipantes?

[image: npsparticipantes]

[image: contrato]

Comment: Copia seu codigo e não imagens, assim fica mais facil da gente olhar seu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo um exemplo CLIENTES e PEDIDOS. Um cliente pode ou não ter pedidos, mas todo pedido pertence a um cliente. Para achar os clientes sem nenhum pedido:

```
select clientes.codigo from clientes
     left outer join pedidos 
         on clientes.codigo = pedidos.cliente
     where pedidos.codigo IS null
```

O rationale é que em LEFT JOIN ou LEFT OUTER JOIN, todas as linhas da tabela "esquerda" aparecem na consulta, mas quando não há linhas correspondentes na tabela "direita", as respectivas colunas valem "null".

Comment: +1 Tenho forte impressão que é duplicata, de qq forma o left join me parece a solução mais elegante.

Answer (score 0):

Não vi qual o campo de referencia entre as tabelas. Porem você pode fazer assim o comando.
Levando em consideração que existe uma chave de referencia em contrato **idNPSParticipantes**.

```
select * from npsparticipantes 
where idNPSParticipantes not in (select idNPSParticipantes from contrato)
```

O resultado seria todos os **npsparticipantes**  que não estão com contrato em **contrato**.

Caso quero se aprofundar com NOT IN e IN, veja aqui
[link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php)